# Is a parcel letterbox based on a tracking code secure?

Tags: physical

I'm making a parcel letterbox. I'm including a barcode scanner that scans the tracking code of the package. The way of entry is simple: by scanning a barcode that's in a list on a local server (which the letterbox downloads in advance to decrease latency). This barcode is normally the tracking code on a parcel.

If the tracking code of the package is in a list, the courier can open the door and can put the package in.

If the tracking code is not in the list, the courier (or whoever else is trying to get in) will be denied entry.

For myself, I use a card with a barcode on it or a manual override (traditional lock).

My question is simple: is this a (relatively) safe way of doing this? Tracking codes aren't specifically protected, but at the same time are not made public either. So based on my simple (simplistic?) reasoning, this is a relatively secure and convenient system. Or am I missing something?

Just to be clear: I'm specifically asking about the way of entry. Assume the letterbox is properly secured, that the door and lock are secure, etc.

Comment: How is the bar code list stored?  Is it encrypted? Does that machine have any connection to your wifi network?

Comment: @iain The bar code list is stored in plain text on both the local server and the letterbox. It's not encrypted on either device. If anyone can (physically) get to the controller of the letterbox, they're already inside the letterbox. The updates indeed happen via wifi.

Comment: Convenient? What happens if someone mails you something you don't specifically plan to receive?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If it's a letter (the vast majority of things that I don't specifically plan to receive are letters), it simply goes into the letter section of the letterbox. If it's a package -- it's rare these days to get a package without tracking code though -- the same thing as before happens: if I'm home, I'll take it, if not, I'll have to go pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly consider encrypting the barcode lists on your server and on your letterbox, if either of these devices have vulnerabilities that allow an attacker to get that list, they essentially have a list of access tokens and your security is comprised.

You should secure the communication between your client and server and ensure your device checks certificates when it retrieves the new barcodes. Attack vectors here being man in the middle sniffing of access tokens (your barcodes) and illicit devices sending you fake tokens if you don't validate the sender. You could consider digitally signing the updates and validating the signature

I'm also thinking of barcode validation, it seems theoretically possible that a sql injection attack could happen with a malicious barcode. Santisation of input, parameterised procedures etc will help mitigate but you may want to research further.

You also need to revoke tokens one they are used. When your delivery driver figures out he can photocopy a barcode and reuse it, security is compromised.

I'm not sure how many possible barcode combinations there are,  I imagine it depends on the specific scheme, but you should probably change your own tokens regularly and consider 2FA.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't use encryption because if they somehow gain access to either device, they will gain access to the list anyway (and potentially more). I could potentially hash it, thus preventing them from retrieving the actual barcode, but if they get to the point where they can get the hash, I've got bigger problems. The communication between the two, however, is secure (https api). The barcodes are a one-time token already; once the package is scanned and delivered, the barcode becomes invalid immediately.